# Чистый javascript. Поймать ошибку в асинхронной функции

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

```
function async (arg, cb) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    throw new Error('error');
    cb();
  }, 200);
}
```

Как, без библиотек, поймать такую ошибку? Доступа к телу функции, само собой, нет.

Comment: сходу тока некрасиво придумал

    var oldst=Error.prototype.toString
    Error.prototype.toString=function() {console.log('catched  test',arguments);return oldst.apply(this,[].slice.call(arguments))}

если там именно Error()

Comment: Как вариант, можно повесить обработчик на `window.onerror`. Но минус в том, что будут отлавливаться все происходящие ошибки.

Comment: @Павел Азанов чет не ловится с onerror. второй некрасивый вариант - переписать Timeout, поставить там try/catch и apply первого аргумента без второго

Comment: @Павел Азанов, Chrome ловит только не пойманные исключенияю

Comment: @alvoro: В этом случае и нужно поймать необработанное исключение. @eicto: Вариант с переписыванием setTimeout хоть и некрасив, он более элегантный. Можно например дать возможность передачи callback функции обработчика исключений если есть необходимость.

Comment: > Но минус в том, что будут отлавливаться все происходящие ошибки.

Произошло недопонимание. Думал, что @Павел Азанов имеет ввиду, что все не пойманные исключения будут обрабатываться.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/sZ8vX/

---

@alvoro так и есть "все не пойманные исключения будут обрабатываться" пойманные не обработаются.

мне кстати больше нравится как раз 

window.addEventListener(errorHandler);
ведь можно и убрать, если поймал или в callback;

правда в любом случае надо бить того кто кидает ошибки в асинхронной функции без обещаний, т.к. любой способ сильно портит жизнь, например действительно, в window.onerror неясно откуда прилетела эта ошибка (есть номер строки например :) и текст ошибки, иногда объект ошибки со стеком, и всё )

Comment: @eicto: опередили немного, http://jsfiddle.net/wVF8D/

Comment: @eicto, ваш первый пример мне не ясен. Пробую тестировать и никакой магии не происходит. http://jsfiddle.net/alvoro/VzzFM/ Да и вообще, по правде говоря, задумку я так и не понял

Comment: это только в консоли работало оказывается, ну можно весь Error переопределить  http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/VzzFM/1/

Comment: @eicto, спасибо. Теперь понял.

Comment: Не здоровайтесь в вопросах. Не пишите про "серебряную пулю", не доказывайте что пытались от ветить на вопрос. У вас могут уточнить в коментариях, тогда можно ответить в комментариях.

Comment: новая версия вопроса, подразумевает, кажется, что вы НЕ МОЖЕТЕ изменить саму функцию, и она дана как есть? Если это так, то стоит, наверное, это попонятнее написать, а то первая мысль, что вы просто спрашиваете, как, вообще делается обработка ошибок в асинх-дж-ск.

Answer (score 1):

Не использовать такой код. По хорошему надо `setTimeout` завернуть в `Promise` и тогда любое исключение спустится по цепочке в первый `catch`.
Если вообще без вариантов - `window.addEventListener('error', function() {})`.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению обработчики исключений (catch, try, throw, finally) и асинхронный JavaScript плохо сочетаются, в силу стэковой, однопотоковой реализации исключений.

Поэтому для обработки ошибок в асинхронном JavaScript применяются кэлбэки, генераторы событий, обещания, домены.

Кэлбэк, обратный вызов:

```
function послатьПисьмо(письмо, адрес, приУспехе, приНеудаче) {
  if (проверить(адрес))
    письмо.отправить(адрес, function () {
      приУспехе(письмо.получитьКодОтправки());
    });
  else
    приНеудаче({ошибка: "Адрес неизвестен"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Никак - возможно, лучше использовать promises-ы и передать из него ошибку (вот как - вопрос, но, вроде бы, было что-то типа return).
Второй вариант - если всё же использовать callback - добавить параметр ошибки

```
cb(err);
```